# Recursively compare filenames in two directories, ignoring contents and return an exit code depending on result

Tags: bash, diff, rsync

This is for a bash script to compare a local and remote mount.
Local files and directories are symlinked to remote, except for new files.

I need to replace `diff` because it compares the contents and becomes very slow over the internet.

I have been trying things like `diff <( ls /local/ ) <( ls /remote/ )` and `diff <( tree /local/ ) <( tree /remote/ )` but cannot make them work, because it they are not recursive or the symlinks get in the way.

`rsync` would be my go to for determining missing files, but I cannot find a way to manage exit codes and integrate into the script.

Script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Backup Command"
sleep 10
while :; do
echo "Testing backup"
if
    diff -r /local/ /remote/ ; then
    echo "diff matches!"    
    break
else
    echo "diff didn't match, waiting for cache"
    sleep 600
fi
done
echo "Finished!"
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong but diff <( find /local/ -printf "%f\n" ) <( find /remote/ -printf "%f\n" ) does not match correctly. I am guessing because they appear in different order and diff needs them to be identical, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `%f` would print only the filename with leading directories removed. So `local/a/file.txt` and `remote/b/file.txt` would be the same file.

Comment: `find /local/` with no added args will list the full pathnames. If you `cd` or pushd to the folder and `find`, you will get relative pathnames. You still need to pass that output through sort. There is also `find -ls` which prints the sizes, though also prints inodes which should be globally unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather simple and obvious and I had tried both, but not together. To make this work, due to the symlinks, `find -L` is required to follow the links and then `sort` is necessary to make them match.

I replaced the diff command with the following:

`diff <( find -L local |sort) <( find -L remote |sort)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmp` to check if two things are the same.

Use `find` to get all the possible paths.

`sort` the paths before passing to `cmp`, so they are the same.

Use zero terminated strings to handle all special characters in filenames.

```
if cmp -s <(cd local && find -print0 | sort -z) <(cd remote && find -print0 | sort -z); then
   echo "local and remote have the same directory and file structure"
else
    echo "Oooh! local and remote differ. Or there was trouble."
fi
```

Comment: i've never come across the `cmp` command before. it is a bit weird though, maybe user error, but when i turn off `-s` for 'silent' in order to know what the differences are, it reports on /dev/fd0 instead of the differences in files.

Comment: `cmp` sees only `<(...)` files. What file should `<(...)` be? It's a temporary pipe or fifo, `/dev/fd/X` usually.